# Content displaying on JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am working on JSP with HTML as markup,I have a large data on the page that is coming dynamically ,how can I show only limited content and rest on the more button click on the same page.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use multiple div elements and hide the divs you don't want to show initially. When the button is clicked just make the hidden divs visible. This can be done with Simple Javascript. Try searching javacript show/hide.

Comment: It has nothing to do with Java, JSP or Servlets. It can be achieved by JavaScript/jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Add this in head section.

```
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function showdiv(){
                document.getElementById('hiddendiv').style.display = 'block';
            }
         </script>
    </head>
```

add this in the body.

```
    <body>
        <div>
            <input type="button" onclick="showdiv()" value="More">
            <div id="hiddendiv" style="dispaly:none;">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Put the content you want to hide in the div called hiddendiv :)

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1)Store it in a `javascript` variable. That means `client side`. And later use it.

2)Don't load that much data on first shot. Make a `server` call later.

A quick question gives you solution among, Why you have to load `data` when you are not going to show on `page` ? :)

**Just fetch when required.**

Comment: Can you please tell me server approach for the same because I am not usin java script

Comment: [You can do with some pagination logic](http://www.roseindia.net/answers/viewqa/Java-Beginners/24202-JSP-Pagination.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
step 1 : store all the data you need in the places you need in your HTML page

step 2 : hide the divs which you want to show on button click

step 3 : on every button click call a JavaScript function to display the hidden content of the div

or send a ajax call to server whenever a button is needed and in response set the value of the field and display

if you share your scenario we can tell which case would be better for you
```